# "this.model" not working on clicked View. Backbone JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, model

**A quick explanation:**
I am working on a backbone app that integrated with Fullcalendar JS. When creating or editing an event, you can click on the calendar and a modal will popup asking for the info. The problem is when the modal pops up I need to use "this.model" to `.get()` info about the current event or `.set()` info about a new event. I keep getting the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined

**My question:**
What is the proper method to set the current model of a clicked view?

Here is some relevant code:

**Model & collection:**

```
 var Event = Backbone.Model.extend({
    methodToURL: {
        'create': addDayURL,
        'update': addDayURL,
        //'delete': '/user/remove'
    },
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.url = model.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

        Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    }
});

var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Event,
    url: allDaysURL
});
```

**Main View**

```
    var EventsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #add_track' : "addTrack",
        'click th.fc-widget-header:not(.fc-first)' : 'updateTrack',
        'click .fc-button-next' : 'switchTracks',
        'click .fc-button-prev' : 'switchTracks'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this); 

        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll);
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne);
        this.collection.bind('change', this.change);            
        this.collection.bind('destroy', this.destroy);



        console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.options.collection2.toJSON()))

        this.trackCollection = JSON.stringify(this.options.collection2.toJSON());
        this.trackObject = jQuery.parseJSON(this.trackCollection);

        this.eventView = new EventView();
        this.trackView = new TrackView();         
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaDay',

            },
            defaultView: 'resourceDay',
            resources: this.trackObject,
            droppable: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
            ignoreTimezone: false,                
            select: this.select,
            eventClick: this.eventClick,
            eventDrop: this.eventDropOrResize,        
            eventResize: this.eventDropOrResize,
            drop: function(date, allDay, ev, ui, res) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // dropped event of resource a to a cell belonging to resource b?
                copiedEventObject.resourceId = res.id;

                //get title of event
                var eventTitle = copiedEventObject.title;

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }
                var event = new Event();
                event.set({"title": eventTitle, "start_at": copiedEventObject.start, "color": null, "allday":copiedEventObject.allDay, "conference_id": conferenceID, "session_type_id": 1, "resource_Id": res.id});
                events.create(event);
            }
        });

        //Goto first event day on initialize
        var start_at = Date.parse(startDate);
        var year = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start_at, 'yyyy');
        var month = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start_at, 'M');
        var day = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start_at, 'dd');

        this.$el.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year , month, day) 
        this.$el.prepend('<button id="add_track" class="btn large-btn green-btn pull-right">Add Track</button>');
    },
    addAll: function() {
        this.$el.fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.collection.toJSON());
    },
    addOne: function(event) {
        this.$el.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event.toJSON());
    }, 
    addTrack: function() {
        //get current day & format date
        date = this.$el.fullCalendar( 'getDate' );
        var formatDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

        //create new track
        var newTrack = new Track;
        newTrack.set({'name': 'Track 1', 'day_date': formatDate, 'conference_id': conferenceID, "session_type_id": 1});

        //save track to DB
        this.options.collection2.create(newTrack);
    },  
    updateTrack: function(track) {
        //var fcRes = this.$el.fullCalendar('clientEvents', event.get('id'))[0];
        //this.trackView.model = track.get('id');
        console.log(this.trackView.model)
        this.trackView.render();  
    },
    switchTracks: function(){
        //alert(this.$el.fullCalendar( 'getDate' ))
    },
    select: function(startDate, endDate, res) {
        this.eventView.collection = this.collection;
        this.eventView.model = new Event({start_at: startDate, end_at: endDate});
        this.eventView.render();            
    },
    eventClick: function(fcEvent) {
        this.eventView.model = this.collection.get(fcEvent.id);
        this.eventView.render();
    },
    change: function(event) {
        // Look up the underlying event in the calendar and update its details from the model
        var fcEvent = this.$el.fullCalendar('clientEvents', event.get('id'))[0];
        console.log(fcEvent);
        fcEvent.title = event.get('title');
        fcEvent.color = event.get('color');
        this.$el.fullCalendar('updateEvent', fcEvent);         
    },
    eventDropOrResize: function(fcEvent) {
        alert(fcEvent.id)
        // Lookup the model that has the ID of the event and update its attributes
        this.collection.get(fcEvent.id).save({start: fcEvent.start, end: fcEvent.end});            
    },
    destroy: function(event) {
        this.$el.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);         
    }        
});
```

**Event Popup Modal View**

```
    var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#eventDialog'),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);           
    },
    render: function() {
        var buttons = {'Ok': this.save};
        if (!this.model.isNew()) {
            _.extend(buttons, {'Delete': this.destroy});
        }
        _.extend(buttons, {'Cancel': this.close});            

        this.$el.dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: (this.model.isNew() ? 'New' : 'Edit') + ' Event',
            buttons: buttons,
            open: this.open
        });
        return this;
    },        
    open: function() {
        this.$('#title').val(this.model.get('title'));
        this.$('#color').val(this.model.get('color'));            
    },        
    save: function(startDate, endDate, res) {
        //copiedEventObject.resourceId = res.id;
        this.model.set({'title': this.$('#title').val(), 'color': this.$('#color').val(), 'conference_id': conferenceID, "session_type_id": 1, 'track_id': 1, /*'resourceId': res.id*/});
        if (this.model.isNew()) {
            this.collection.create(this.model, {success: this.close, wait: true});
        } else {
            this.model.save({}, {success: this.close});
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        this.$el.dialog('close');
    },
    destroy: function() {
        this.model.destroy({success: this.close});
    }        
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a working JSFiddle with this example?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your calendar view does not have a model associated with it. You will need to pass the model into the calendar view when instantiating it. When you call `this.eventView = new EventView();` you are not providing it with a reference to your underlying model in your main view.

Comment: I tried to create a JSfiddle but without the serverside stuff it just give errors... I also tried your suggestion but am stil getting the same error. I think it maybe have to do with this line `this.eventView.model = this.collection.get(fcEvent.id);` b/c that is where the new eventView model gets set. But I can't gfigure out why that is coming up undefined. also, I have been working off of this tutorial, http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/, which may have some more concise/clean code to look at. Thank you :)

Comment: better yet, that isn't populated b/c of this line `var fcEvent = this.$el.fullCalendar('clientEvents', event.get('id'))[0];` on the change event. Any idea why that would be undefined??

Comment: Ok, so just to clarify, your main view is a calendar view using Fullcalendar.js and the modal view opens when you click on one of the events from the full calendar view, and that part is working, this issue is you want the event model to be the model of the modal that is opened is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. I am not sure how to pass the event model to the EventView when said event is clicked.

Comment: What does `this.collection.get(fcEvent.id);` equal in the click event when you log it to the console?

Comment: Ok, this is interesting. If I just click on the calendar and create an event, then click that event to open it, it works! and the console logs the child event! BUT, if I use the drag and drop functionality I added, then try to click that event once it is created in the `drop:` event of the calendar, it comes up undefined. But I checked the DB and the event model was create and stored.

Comment: I wonder if it's because your `_bindAll` is done in initialize but the drag and drop functionality binds after the DOM has loaded which is too late